# Prevent docker from creating image from cache

Tags: caching, docker, dockerfile, fig

The issue I am having is I have made some configuration changes. I have a fig.yml file that starts up all of my docker images. So i changed necessary config files however when i do ./fig up it just recreates each docker image. What is the command that you can use to make docker rebuild the image without cache from a fig.yml file ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm thinking the answer to this is ./fig up --no-recreate

Comment: correction `fig build --no-cache && fig up`

Comment: If it works for you, just answer your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be looking for `fig build`. By default `fig up` will rebuild containers, but not images. This has been a [source of confusion](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/614) for a while.

> If you change a service's Dockerfile or the contents of its build directory, you can run `fig build` to rebuild [the image]. ([source](https://docs.docker.com/compose/cli/#build))